# Read The Docs/Sphinx doing weird errors on build

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to make docs for a python API wrapper that I am making (you can view the docs code [here](https://github.com/craziiace/hypyxel/tree/master/docs)), and when I try to make a build on the read the docs dashboard, I get

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.5
loading translations [en]... done
making output directory...
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [readthedocs]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index


Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 304, in build_main
   app.build(args.force_all, filenames)
 File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 341, in build
   self.builder.build_update()
 File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 347, in build_update
   len(to_build))
 File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 360, in build
   updated_docnames = set(self.read())
 File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/builders/__init__.py", line 472, in read
   self.env.doc2path(self.config.master_doc))
sphinx.errors.SphinxError: master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/checkouts/latest/docs/contents.rst not found

Sphinx error:
master file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/hypyxel/checkouts/latest/docs/contents.rst not found
```

Does this mean I need a contents.rst file? Or is this a problem with read the docs/sphinx? Or is this something else?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is a strange parsing issue with `:caption: Contents:`. Perhaps remove the trailing `:` and try again?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have a index.rst file? The default master file name was contents.rst before Sphinx 2.0. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html?highlight=master#confval-master_doc

Comment: Yes, I do have an `indes.rst` file.

Comment: OK, then upgrade Sphinx to a newer version (at least 2.0). If you cannot do that, add `master_doc = index` in conf.py.